# catkin_make Error: Could NOT find TinyXML2 (missing: TinyXML2_LIBRARY TinyXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I get this error when I try to compile my packages with catkin_make on a BeagleBone board (ARM).
I have these packages installed (aptitude search tinyxml): libtinyxml-dev, libtinyxml2-2v5, libtinyxml2.6.2v5

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Here is the log:

```
root@beaglebone:~/RBE-2002# catkin_make
Base path: /root/RBE-2002
Source space: /root/RBE-2002/src
Build space: /root/RBE-2002/build
Devel space: /root/RBE-2002/devel
Install space: /root/RBE-2002/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /root/RBE-2002/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/root/RBE-2002/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/RBE-2002/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/root/RBE-2002/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /root/RBE-2002/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /root/RBE-2002/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 29 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - class_loader
-- ~~  - ros_control (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_controllers (metapackage)
-- ~~  - pluginlib
-- ~~  - rqt_joint_trajectory_controller
-- ~~  - controller_manager_msgs
-- ~~  - four_wheel_steering_msgs
-- ~~  - hardware_interface
-- ~~  - combined_robot_hw
-- ~~  - controller_interface
-- ~~  - force_torque_sensor_controller
-- ~~  - forward_command_controller
-- ~~  - effort_controllers
-- ~~  - imu_sensor_controller
-- ~~  - position_controllers
-- ~~  - controller_manager
-- ~~  - diff_drive_controller
-- ~~  - gripper_action_controller
-- ~~  - joint_limits_interface
-- ~~  - joint_state_controller
-- ~~  - joint_trajectory_controller
-- ~~  - rqt_controller_manager
-- ~~  - sweep_ros
-- ~~  - controller_manager_tests
-- ~~  - combined_robot_hw_tests
-- ~~  - transmission_interface
-- ~~  - turtlebotmini
-- ~~  - urdf_geometry_parser
-- ~~  - velocity_controllers
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'class_loader'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(class_loader)
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Searching for Poco library...
--   Found Poco!
-- components found: Foundation.
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ros_control'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_control/ros_control)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ros_controllers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_controllers/ros_controllers)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'pluginlib'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(pluginlib)
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
 Could NOT find TinyXML2 (missing: TinyXML2_LIBRARY TinyXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
 /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindTinyXML2.cmake:65 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
 pluginlib/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/RBE-2002/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/RBE-2002/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

CMakeLists.txt of PluginLib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pluginlib)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS class_loader rosconsole roslib cmake_modules)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)
find_package(TinyXML2 REQUIRED)

catkin_python_setup()

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS class_loader rosconsole roslib
  DEPENDS Boost TinyXML2
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${TinyXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(plugin_tool src/plugin_tool.cpp)
target_link_libraries(plugin_tool ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${TinyXML2_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS plugin_tool
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY include/pluginlib/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})

install(FILES share/pluginlib/typed_class_loader_template.cpp
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})

install(PROGRAMS scripts/plugin_macro_update
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_library(test_plugins EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL SHARED test/test_plugins.cpp)

  catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_utest test/utest.cpp)
  if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}_utest)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_utest ${TinyXML2_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_utest test_plugins)
  endif()

  include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
  check_cxx_compiler_flag("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
  if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_unique_ptr_test test/unique_ptr_test.cpp)
    if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}_unique_ptr_test)
      target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_unique_ptr_test ${TinyXML2_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
      set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_unique_ptr_test PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -std=c++11 LINK_FLAGS -std=c++11)
      add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_unique_ptr_test test_plugins)
    endif()
  endif()

endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277748/catkin_make-error:-could-not-find-tinyxml2-(missing:-tinyxml2_library-tinyxml2_include_dir)/) by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-11**:
We're going to need to see your `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) on 2017-12-11**:
The error comes when compiling the [pluginlib package](https://github.com/ros/pluginlib) However, this is a standard ROS library, so the CMakeLists.txt theoretically should be fine. I will post it in my post anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got it to work! Essenially, I installed the libtinyxml2-dev on top of everything. This apparently added the header files ROS was looking for. It now works fine!

This is what I get when searching with apt on my BeagleBone

```
user@beaglebone:~/RBE-2002# apt search tinyxml
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libtinyxml-dev/oldstable,now 2.6.2-2 armhf [installed]
  TinyXml library - header and static library

libtinyxml-doc/oldstable 2.6.2-2 all
  TinyXml library - documentation files

libtinyxml2-2/oldstable,now 2.2.0-1 armhf [installed]
  C++ XML parsing library

libtinyxml2-dev/oldstable,now 2.2.0-1 armhf [installed]
  TinyXML2 library - header and static library

libtinyxml2.6.2/oldstable,now 2.6.2-2 armhf [installed]
  C++ XML parsing library

libtinyxml2.6.2-dbg/oldstable 2.6.2-2 armhf
  TinyXml library - debug files
```

---

Originally posted by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) with karma: 113 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-11**:\

> I installed the libtinyxml2-dev on top of everything. This apparently added the header files ROS was looking for.

how did you install dependencies in the first place? Shouldn't `rosdep install ..` have installed the dev lib for you?

**Comment by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) on 2018-10-25**:
Honestly don't remember if I tried that, but a possible problem would be that the BeagleBone is running on an ARM processor, and I had to compile ROS for it specifically.

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2019-08-11**:
yes correct...all I had to do was sudo apt-get install libtinyxml2-dev ..and it worked